# About the baggage formalities at Delhi airport during a travel between Tokyo and Ahmedabad and vice versa

Tags: transit, luggage, jal

I am travelling from Tokyo to Ahmedabad via Delhi with a JAL-Vistara combination.

I have one question related to carrying baggage between Tokyo and Ahmedabad, and vice versa.

Does this code-shared flight have a through check-in as stated on [Vistara website](https://www.airvistara.com/trip/interline-partners)? Meaning we don't have to re-check baggage at Delhi Airport and we will get our baggage at Ahmedabad?

Also is the same true for the return?

Comment: Can you provide the flight numbers? And is the entire booking on one ticket?

Comment: @RedBaron: The flight numbers are JL 749 and UK 959. Yes the booking is entirely under one ticket and same PNR for whole round-trip.

Comment: As Delhi is your last point of exit from India and first point of entry into India, I think your customs check will be done here. Informally, this may mean that while your luggage is through checked you will have to manually claim it and then hand it over to the airlines guys after walking through customs (atleast on return). I have no source or experience of such a thing and hence am not posting this as an answer. It would be better to call airlines and ask for clarification.